# Query timeseries in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have the following table with group members count:

```
CREATE TABLE "group_members_count" (
  group_id INTEGER,
  time     TIMESTAMP,
  members_count INTEGER
)
```

I want to query members count for specific group and time interval (from, to) with custom period.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 
  "group_id",
  date_trunc('day', "time") as period,
  max(count) as value
FROM
  "group_members_count"
WHERE
  "channel_id" IN (123, 124) AND ("time"::date >= '2017-11-02' AND "time"::date <= '2017-11-02')
GROUP BY 
  "period", "group_id"
ORDER BY
  "group_id", "period"
```

As expected, I will get the **maximum** value per day, but I need the **latest**.

Comment: `max(("time"::date)` ?..

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `array_agg()` and take the first element:

```
SELECT group_id,
       date_trunc('day', "time") as period,
       max(count) as value,
       array_agg(count order by "time" desc)[1]
FROM group_members_count
WHERE channel_id IN (123, 124) AND
      ("time"::date >= '2017-11-02' AND "time"::date <= '2017-11-02')
GROUP BY period, group_id
ORDER BY group_id, period
```